# Bizarre template error message with gcc 4.6

Tags: c++, templates, gcc4

I'm getting a truly bizarre error message from gcc 4.6 about a template member function. Here is a minimal example:

```
template<typename T>
class Pimpl
{
public:
    Pimpl(const Pimpl&) {}

private:
    T* clone_(const T*);
};

template<typename T>
template<typename P>
T*
Pimpl<T>::clone_(const T*)
{
    return new P(static_cast<const P&>(*p));
}
```

Here is the error:

```
$ c++ -c y.cpp
y.cpp:14:1: error: prototype for ‘T* Pimpl<T>::clone_(const T*)’ does not match any in  class ‘Pimpl<T>’
y.cpp:8:8: error: candidate is: T* Pimpl<T>::clone_(const T*)
```

Note that the non-matching prototype is exactly the same as the candidate one.

What gives?

Comment: No it's not. The candidate one is not a member template.

Comment: That "clone" function doesn't seem to make any sense at all. It's much more like a "convert-and-allocate" function.

Answer (score 3):

They're different because of the `template <typename P>`. The Comeau error message (as generated at http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout) highlights the problem you're having:

```
error: template nesting depth does not match the previous declaration of function "Pimpl<T>::clone_"
```

It's worth mentioning in general that:

(a) The Comeau compiler is known for producing particularly good error messages.

(b) Compiling with multiple compilers will often given you insights that you might not have had otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a member template, you have to declare it as such:

```
template <typename T>
class Pimpl
{
    // ...

    template <typename P>
    static P * clone(T const * p)
    {
        return new P(static_cast<P const &>(*p));
    }
};
```

I also made the member template `static` because it doesn't seem to depend on an object instance, and I defined it inline, because you have to supply the template definition in the header anyway, and I fixed the return type. (But I fail to see how the templated `clone` function makes any sense...)

Comment: Ah, thanks for that! I know about the `static` and `inline`. I just reduced this to something as simple as possible. The `clone_` function arises in the context of pimpls and incomplete types. See Alan Griffith's `Grin_ptr`: [link](http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/overload72-FINAL.pdf).